# How do you get a list of paused applications on an android?

Tags: java, android

I am getting a list of all applications on an android phone using

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

I want to traverse through each of these applications and see which ones are paused (running in the background and can be closed).

Currently I know how to check if one of these applications in stopped:

```
private static boolean isStopped(ApplicationInfo appInfo) {
    return ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_STOPPED) != 0);
}
```

But, as I said earlier, I am concerned as to whether or not these applications are paused.

Comment: Generally, apps cannot obtain information about running processes in modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah that is an issue I have been running into quite a bit. But I figured that since you can get a list of all apps on the phone and details about whether or not they are stopped, that you would be able to figure out whether or not they are paused.

Comment: In this case, "stopped" refers to apps that either have never been run since installation or have been force-stopped by the user (e.g., through Settings). It does not mean "apps that are not running".